# Eclipse can't generate getters and setters in a special case; Need help tracking the problem down

Tags: java, eclipse

After I create classes in a certain package, and add an enum declaration inside the class, I can no longer generate getters and setters.   I suspect it has something to do with the project settings or setup, but I'm not sure where to look.  If I make the same class in its own project, I don't see the problem.

```
public class ExampleClass {

    private enum SampleEnum {
        A, B, C;
    }

    private SampleEnum e;

    private String variableToGenerateCodeOn;

}
```

When I try to generate getters and setters for variableToGenerateCodeOn, I get this error: `cannot analyze selected field 'variableToGenerateCodeOn'`

***Edit*** 
When I resolved the errors with tomcat, the problem didn't go away.  Of two others on my team, one was able to repro the bug with the same code, the other wasn't.  I am now *guessing* it has to do with some workspace settings, but I am open to additional ideas.  The original thought is still preserved below:

***Outdated/Ruled-out idea***
I have several errors from some included tomcat files.  One of them that might be applicable:

```
Description: Enumeration cannot be resolved to a type
On Detail: sessionDetail.jsp
In Folder: {myproject}/tomcat/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/jsp
Location: line 104
```

Comment: I tried it in my Eclipse, it worked, no errors.

Comment: Right click the project -> Java Compiler -> Whats the compliance settings? enums as a keyword was introduced in 1.5, hope that helps?

Comment: @Rajeev, compiler compliance level is 1.6 (default).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a defect in Eclipse Indigo. The presence of some nested declaration confuses the getter/setter code. You can report it in bugzilla. For now, move the enum out to its own file or type the getters and setters by paw. [dog joke]

Comment: I'd love to report the bug, but I am not sure what makes it reproducible yet.  That's why I am looking for help to track it down.

Comment: It happened to me today in a project with no other errors, but I didn't take the time to do a full isolation. I betcha that if you create the exact same package in a clean project and put the exact same nested enum in a class, you'll hit the same behavior and can make a bugzilla.

Comment: @bmarguiles, I thought so too--but when I tried creating the same package name, I had no luck reproducing the error.  Good idea, though.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse behaves quite strange and nondeterministically when there are errors - even if they are in a different file and seem totally unrelated. So try to remove those errors, then Eclipse will probably be able to generate the setters and getters (your example works for me).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error for the eNums keyword as I used the class name 'practice'.
Eclipse has a errorshot when you declare the class,method or variables starting with
pract,ract,ria.

You can try to remove word variable ('variableToGenerateCodeOn')in your variable declaration, trying some other word could help you,

or check anywhere else in your code rhyming any declaration as shown above.